# Work shift code bug in PHP

Tags: php, time, clock, strtotime, shift

I have a little problem with php code what finds out how many hours employee worked in nighttime and how many hours in daytime.

Code is here:

```
function intersection($s1, $e1, $s2, $e2) {
    if ($e1 < $s2)
            return 0;
    if ($s1 > $e2)
            return 0;
    if ($s1 < $s2)
            $s1 = $s2;
    if ($e1 > $e2)
            $e1 = $e2;
    return $e1 - $s1;
}

    $start = strtotime("07:00");
    $end = strtotime("17:30");
    // $end = strtotime("05:30") + 3600*24; // the work ended at 05:30 morning of the next day

    $morning_start = strtotime("07:00");
    $morning_end = strtotime("15:00");

    $afternoon_start = strtotime("15:00");
    $afternoon_end = strtotime("23:00");

    $night_start = strtotime("23:00");
    $night_end = strtotime("07:00") + 3600*24; // 07:00 of next day, add 3600*24 seconds

    echo "morning: " . intersection( $start, $end, $morning_start, $morning_end ) / 3600 . " hours\n";
    echo "afternoon: " . intersection( $start, $end, $afternoon_start, $afternoon_end ) / 3600 . " hours\n";
    echo "night: " . intersection( $start, $end, $night_start, $night_end ) / 3600 . " hours\n";
```

I'm not author of this code. Copyrights belong to user Javi R and the code if from this question: [Calculating shift hours worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136864/calculating-shift-hours-worked) . I made this, because original question is about 3 years old and they don't answer there anymore.

That Javi R code works almost perfectly but there is some kind of bug what I can't find.

My shift times are simplier: 22:00 -> 07:00 = nightwork, 07:00 -> 22:00 = daywork .

I think thats not important how these shifts or something are. I tried with original code too, but bug remains.

I got wrong answer with Javi R version if working hours are like 22:30 -> 08:00 (Result: day = 0 hours, night = 8:30 hours) and 20:00 -> 10:00 (Result: day = 2 hours, night = 9 hours) but right answer with worktime like 23:00 -> 07:00 (Result: day = 0 hours, night = 7 hours).

Correct one will be:

22:30 -> 08:00 = 8,5h nighttime and 1h daytime
20:00 -> 10:00 = 9h nighttime and 2 + 3h daytime

I hope you are able to fix my problem and that bug, so that code would work perfectly and could help others with same problem.

Thanks for helping and thanks Javi R for doing that code.

Comment: I'm having the same problems. Can you help me? [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016394/calculating-shift-hours-worked-and-detecting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem arises when working hours overflow one working day.
In the case of your code, a day goes from 7am to 7am (morning 7->15, afternoon 15->22, night 22->7).
If one works from 22pm to 8am, one works 10 hours the first day and 1 hour the second day. The code propose does not take in account such overflow.

A (far form being perfect) fix could be to change the function `intersection()` as follows:

```
function intersection($s1, $e1, $s2, $e2,$day) {

    return subintersection($s1,$e1,$s2,$e2)+subintersection($s1,$e1,$s2+$day,$e2+$day);
}

function subintersection($s1, $e1, $s2, $e2) {
    if ($e1 < $s2)
            return 0;
    if ($s1 > $e2)
            return 0;
    if ($s1 < $s2)
            $s1 = $s2;
    if ($e1 > $e2)
            $e1 = $e2;
    return $e1 - $s1;
}
```

and change your call to `intersection()`. for example, for morning :

```
$day=3600*24;
echo "morning: " . (intersection( $start, $end, $morning_start, $morning_end,$day))/3600 . " hours\n<br/>"
```

Comment: So you mean that it only deal with 24 hour and everything what is out of that is not accepted? If working hours are for example from 17:00PM to 07:00AM its alright but when workinghours are from 17:00PM to 07:01 AM, its not alright? So that one minute is overflow and it would not be accepted?

Comment: yes, you are totally right. I just update my answer to propose a fix.

Comment: What is that $day? Edit: sorry, you answered it already.

I just found out that it shows only zero-s if there is no +24 added to the $end. Its in the comment there.

Comment: yes of course, if `$end` is before `$start` nothing works. A test could be added to automatically add `+$day` to `$end` if it is before `$start`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Finally. Other solutions are welcome.

Comment: I made mine version little simplier. I removed $day from your version because it is just 24 in my case and I removed intersection function. I had already $day and $night variables. $day was intersection( $start, $end, $morning_start, $morning_end) and $night was intersection( $start, $end, $night_start, $night_end).

So I just added these function again and that 24 hour too. So in my code it ise now that way:

$day = intersection( $start, $end, $morning_start, $morning_end,$day) + intersection( $start, $end, $morning_start + 24, $morning_end + 24)